# cakephp: AppController conflict with other controllers

Tags: html, arrays, cakephp

The code for the App Controller is for the functionalities of the nav bar.

AppController

```
 public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->RememberMe->restoreLoginFromCookie();
        $this->set('server_root', Router::url('/'));

        $this->loadModel('Recipe');
    $this->set('recipes', $this->Recipe->find('all'));
```

Everything works fine every page shows the nav bar and every nav bar from all the pages functions properly
until I add a dropdown selection that needs to be populated with "Recipe" values.

KitchenController

This is the code that I use to populate the dropdown selection

```
$this->set('recipes', $this->Recipe->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Recipe.description'))));
```

It filled the dropdown although not exactly the values that I want to get but a little close, however it also affected the nav bars which causes some errors like undefined variables, which weren't there before. Somehow it affects the navbar that also uses the Model "Recipe".

Question 1: How can I isolate the dropdown selection so that it won't affect the nav bar?Controller issue
Question 2: How can I call a specific field in an array?because currently this code

```
$this->set('recipes', $this->Recipe->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Recipe.description'))));
```

returns the id,date and description, I only need the description.

Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: there's no need for the `server_root` variable - you can access the router everywhere. It is a _bad idea_ to be loading a model and setting variables like that in your beforeFilter; if all pages need that put it in your before _Render_ function at least then you're no finding recipes even when the request is redirected or otherwise doesn't have a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are setting same View variable name "recipes" which is the issue when you want to use the same variable with two different output. You must change the variable names to like:

**nav_recipes or recipes**

or something which is precise to your application context